# Listview of clickable images, unable to open other activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, custom-adapter

[Edited]I wanted to make a listview of images and on clicking them another activity should open(a separate activity for each clickable) but the setOnItemClickListener is not working.

This is my Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.priyanshu.justforfun;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();

        blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two));
        blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four));
        blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six));
        blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.eight));
        blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.nine,R.drawable.ten));

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, blocks, R.color.gray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
```

This is Imageadapter.java-

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Block> {

    private int mColorResourceId;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Block> words, int colorResourceId) {
        super(context, 0, words);
        mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Block currentBlock = getItem(position);

         ImageButton iconView1 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.im1);
         ImageButton iconView2 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.im2);

        iconView1.setImageResource(currentBlock.getImage1ResourceId());
        iconView2.setImageResource(currentBlock.getImage2ResourceId());

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

This is Block.java-

```
public class Block {

    private int mImage1ResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
    private int mImage2ResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;

    private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

    public Block(int Image1ResourceId ,int Image2ResourceId) {
        mImage1ResourceId = Image1ResourceId;
        mImage2ResourceId = Image2ResourceId;
    }

    public int getImage1ResourceId(){  return mImage1ResourceId;}

    public int getImage2ResourceId(){  return mImage2ResourceId;}
}
```

This is List_item.xml

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_item">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_splash"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_splash"
        android:id="@+id/im2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are trying to allocate 74649612 bytes. This is equivalent to a 8640 x 8640-pixel image. **This is much too large**. Make smaller drawable resources, and make sure that you have them in the proper density directory for whatever density you are targeting.

Comment: @CommonsWare the combined size of all the images is 177.6 kB so i guess there some other problem in app.

Comment: You are confusing disk space with memory usage. Images are stored compressed on disk. The memory usage is for the uncompressed image (4 bytes per pixel). My calculation was off -- it's equivalent to a 4320x4320 pixel image.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can i decrease memory usage

Comment: Use lower-resolution images, and put them in the proper drawable resource directory based on the density.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did as you suggested and  app finally opens fine in my mobile without any error message but still the click function is not working.  I want to start another activity on clicking each image.Please look into it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've changed the question for better understanding of the issue , please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CommonsWare said:

> You are trying to allocate 74649612 bytes. This is equivalent to a
>   8640 x 8640-pixel image. This is much too large.

You have to use much smaller sized images in drawable as this allocates too much memory. Moreover, You can Use **Glide/Picasso** to load your Images.Glide handles bitmap decoding, disk caching efficiently to ensure lesser memory allocation and avoide out of memory error.

In order to use Glide to your project, First, Add this to dependency in app gradle file :

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:xx.x.x'  // According to your compileSdkVersion

}
```

Inside your `getView()`:

**Replace:**

```
 iconView1.setImageResource(currentBlock.getImage1ResourceId());
 iconView2.setImageResource(currentBlock.getImage2ResourceId());
```

**With:**

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(currentBlock.getImage1ResourceId())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   //Use low res image as placeholder
                .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)      //Use low res image as error image
                .into(iconView1);

 Glide.with(context)
                .load(currentBlock.getImage2ResourceId())                   
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
                .into(iconView2);
```

To open different activities on click different items use the following code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0){
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity1.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity2.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                }
                // Do as above for rest of the positions
            }
        });
```

Comment: Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
<a href="openFile:/home/priyanshu/AndroidStudioProjects/JustForFun/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: i used new lower resolution images and now app opens fine but the click feature is still not working, can you do something about it. I want to open diferent activity on clicking on different image.

Comment: my onItemClickListener doesn't work. I've changed the question please take a look at it.

Comment: I would suggest you to use GridView instead of ListView for your project. Check this tutorial out - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/ You may find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks!! that proved a lot useful

Answer (score 0):

Having only 6 images shouldn't max out your memory. The only thing I can see making problem here is size of your images.

Did you create appropriate drawable folders with proper file size?

Comment: The combined size of all the images is only 177.6 kB so there's some other problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it's occurring for images. You need to load the high resolution image using Bitmap or any library. Or for simple way, add the images to drawable nodpi directory. It won't scale the image.